# Node.js source code build giving segmentation fault on ARM

Tags: node.js, segmentation-fault, arm, v8, ubuntu-12.10

tl;dr: I tried to install node.js on my ARMv7-based [Cubox](http://www.solid-run.com/products/cubox) running Ubuntu 12.10 (quantal). When compiling node.js from source (see "Second attempt" below), `node` produces a segmentation fault. What can I do here?

### First attempt

First of all, I tried to install node.js via the package manager, following the instructions for Ubuntu that are given here: [Installing Node.js via package manager: Ubuntu, Mint](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu-mint)

Adding the repository mentioned there using `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js` seems to work fine:

```
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 Evented I/O for V8 javascript. Node's goal is to provide an easy way to build scalable network programs
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpp0owib/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpp0owib/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key C7917B12 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpp0owib/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key C7917B12: public key "Launchpad chrislea" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

However, `sudo apt-get install nodejs` gives me the error:

```
E: Unable to locate package nodejs
```

I assume this is because I have an ARM-based system. As far as I can tell [from the package details](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/+packages), the repo only contains builds for i386 and amd64. Is my assumption right?

### Second attempt

So my next attempt was to install node.js from source. I used the instructions given in the following gist: [Node.js and NPM in 30 seconds](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814#file-node-and-npm-in-30-seconds-sh). Everything seems to work, including `make install`. But the execution of the `install.sh` script in the last line of the gist fails since `node` produces a segmentation fault. Now I wonder what I can do to properly install node.js on my machine?

In order to illustrate my problem, here is some output:

**install.sh output**

This is the ouput of `install.sh` after running `make install`, as described in the gist installation instructions mentioned above.

```
cyroxx@cubox:~/node-latest-install$ curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  7882  100  7882    0     0  11251      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 14984
tar=/bin/tar
version:
tar (GNU tar) 1.26
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
install npm@latest
fetching: http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.2.21.tgz
Segmentation fault
Segmentation fault
You need node  to run this program.
node --version reports: v0.10.7
Please upgrade node before continuing.
It failed
```

**node output**

```
cyroxx@cubox:~/node-latest-install$ node
Segmentation fault
```

**make Debug build**

Running `make` with `BUILDTYPE=Debug` produces this output:

```
cyroxx@cubox:~/node-latest-install$ make -C out BUILDTYPE=Debug
make: Entering directory `/home/cyroxx/node-latest-install/out'
  CXX(target) /home/cyroxx/node-latest-install/out/Debug/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/arm/stub-cache-arm.o
../deps/v8/src/arm/stub-cache-arm.cc: In function 'void v8::internal::ProbeTable(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::MacroAssembler*, v8::internal::Code::Flags, v8::internal::StubCache::Table, v8::internal::Register, v8::internal::Register, v8::internal::Register, v8::internal::Register, v8::internal::Register, v8::internal::Register)':
../deps/v8/src/arm/stub-cache-arm.cc:106:15: error: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Werror=type-limits]
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [/home/cyroxx/node-latest-install/out/Debug/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/arm/stub-cache-arm.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/cyroxx/node-latest-install/out'
```

What's wrong here? Is this a bug in the ARM implementation of V8? Maybe any compiler flags that are not (properly) set? Anything else? I am totally stuck.

Comment: Please provide the actual error message. Is there really no further output from the script? Does it have debug flags?

Comment: I added the output of the `install.sh` script as well as the output of `node` to clarify the observed error. I am currently trying to build and install a debug version, but this may take a while due to the hardware limitations.

Comment: Just added the output of the make debug build. The question is now quite long, any ideas on how it can be improved are welcome. I hope that my problem becomes clear now, but I will provide any further information if needed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just letting you know that you're not alone in this; I'm trying to install the latest version of node on my ARM-based Chromebook and am running into the same exact problem you are.
Your assumption about apt not installing node from the PPA b/c there are builds only for i386 and amd64 is correct.

Comment: @dskang: Good to know. In the meanwhile, I tried to cross-compile using the following solution, but it failed on ARM as well (with a different error, though): http://www.nodejs-news.com/nodejs-tech/ruby-to-build-nodejs-raspberrypi/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I had this problem too on a few different ARM computers. Compiling without the snapshot feature worked for me. Snapshot is a V8 feature that allows node to start faster, and there seems to be a bug for ARM.

```
./configure --without-snapshot
make
sudo make install
```

http://www.armhf.com/index.php/node-js-for-the-beaglebone-black/

Comment: Thanks to Jeremy. "nvm install 0.10 --without-snapshot" built a working 0.10.12 for me on my Samsung chromebook.

Comment: Worked for me under Debian/wheezy on an Android chroot.

Comment: Worked on OlinuXino A10

Comment: Thanks it worked on my samsung chromebook for node version o.10.32

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble building on a Samsung Chromebook XE303C12I with [Crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton) running Unity, even with `--without-snapshot` and `--with-arm-float-abi=hard`, so I used the precompiled binaries for Linux ARM devices.

Binaries can be found in the release directory at nodejs.org/dist/{version number}

For example, the ARM binary for v0.10.24 can be downloaded [here].(http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.24/node-v0.10.24-linux-arm-pi.tar.gz)

Here's a [script](https://gist.github.com/TooTallNate/3288316) to download and install a binary. Once you have node installed, make sure to add `path/to/bin/node` to your `$PATH`.