# Libraries compatibilty by cross-compiling node for armv5

Tags: c, node.js, arm, cross-compiling

I try to cross-compile [node](https://github.com/joyent/node) for my QNAP armv5te machine, on my Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop x64.

*A node QPKG exists in QNAP App-center, but its version is old (0.8.22).*
Here are informations about the server :

> Linux SERVERNAME 3.4.6 #1 Mon Dec 29 06:00:47 CST 2014 armv5tel unknown
>   **Processor name**  : Feroceon 88F6281 rev 1 (v5l) @ 1.2 GHz
>   **BogoMIPS**        : 1196.85
>   **Features**        : swp half thumb fastmult edsp
>   **CPU implementer** : 0x56
>   **CPU architecture**: 5TE
>   **CPU variant**     : 0x2
>   **CPU part**        : 0x131
>   **CPU revision**    : 1
>   **Hardware**        : Feroceon-KW
>   **ARM Revision**    : 0000
>   **Serial**          : 0000000000000000

Here's the command I used on my desktop :

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install emdebian-archive-keyring
apt-get install libc6-armel-cross libc6-dev-armel-cross
apt-get install binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi
apt-get install gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabi
apt-get install g++-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabi
apt-get install u-boot-tools
apt-get install libncurses5-dev
ln -s /user/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.7 /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
ln -s /user/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-4.7 /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-g++

wget http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.10.35/node-v0.10.35.tar.gz
tar -zxf node-v0.10.35.tar.gz
cd node-v0.10.35

export TOOL_PREFIX="arm-linux-gnueabi"
export CC="${TOOL_PREFIX}-gcc"
export CXX="${TOOL_PREFIX}-g++"
export AR="${TOOL_PREFIX}-ar"
export RANLIB="${TOOL_PREFIX}-ranlib"
export LINK="${CXX}"
export CCFLAGS="-march=armv5te -mfpu=softfp -marm"
export CXXFLAGS="-march=armv5te -mno-unaligned-access"
export OPENSSL_armcap=5
export GYPFLAGS="-Darmeabi=soft -Dv8_can_use_vfp_instructions=false -Dv8_can_use_unaligned_accesses=false -Darmv7=0"
export VFP3=off
export VFP2=off

./configure --without-snapshot --dest-cpu=arm --dest-os=linux --prefix="/root/.nvm/v0.10.35"
make -j 4
make install
tar -zcf node-v0.10.35-linux-armv5.tar.gz v0.10.35
```

The compilation doesn't show any failures with these parameters. So after that I send the tarball to my QNAP server:

```
scp /root/.nvm/node-v0.10.35-linux-armv5.tar.gz admin@SERVERNAME:/share/HDA_DATA/.qpkg/nodejs
ssh SERVERNAME -l admin
cd /share/HDA_DATA/.qpkg/nodejs
tar -zxf node-v0.10.35-linux-armv5.tar.gz
ln -s v0.10.35 node
```

All my env variables are already set on my server. Now I can test node binary...

```
# node -v
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_ARM_1.3.3' not found (required by node)
node: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by node)
node: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by node)
node: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by node)
```

Finally I have an error because C libraries are not the same on Ubuntu and Qnap, for Ubuntu desktop I have `ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.5) 2.19` and on QNAP `ldd (GNU libc) 2.5`.

**libc-dev** and **libstdc++** are packages handled by Optware ipkg on Qnap, (old versions too).

My question is what is the better way to fix this problem ? Force updating libs on server ? (and how to do that ?) Or maybe use static libs during compilation ? ( and how to do that too ?) Or other options ?

---

**EDIT:**

After my conversation with artless-noise, I understood I had several ways to fix library dependencies...

Dependencies in question:

```
# ldd /opt/bin/node
/opt/node/bin/node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_ARM_1.3.3' not found (required by /opt/node/bin/node)
/opt/node/bin/node: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /opt/node/bin/node)
/opt/node/bin/node: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by /opt/node/bin/node)
/opt/node/bin/node: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by /opt/node/bin/node)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xb6ed2000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0xb6ec3000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb6de2000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xb6d32000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6d1e000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xb6cfe000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb6bca000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.3 (0xb6ee4000)
```

- **Copy libraries from Ubuntu GCC to the target machine, and override default ones :**
  It could be really dangerous, and may brick the system. To more, my goal is to create a QPKG for QNAP community, so ask people to override their C libs is not a really nice method.
- **Copy libraries and cohabit with original ones :**
  A nice method, just need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to a dir containing newest libs for the application. But I found an error using this method, again with c++ lib.

**The error:**

```
node: symbol lookup error: /opt/node/lib/c/libstdc++.so.6: undefined symbol: _ZNSt11__timepunctIcE2idE, version GLIBCXX_3.4
```

- **Create a static application :**
  Finally, I found the way to do it without any errors during compilation, and during execution on the target machine. Just need to add some flags.

**New flags:**

```
export CCFLAGS="-march=armv5te -mfpu=softfp -marm -static-libgcc"
export CXXFLAGS="-march=armv5te -mno-unaligned-access -static-libstdc++"
export LDFLAGS="-static"
```

**Checking dynamic library links:**

```
# ldd /opt/bin/node
    not a dynamic executable
# npm version
{ test: '1.0.0',
  npm: '2.3.0',
  ares: '1.9.0-DEV',
  http_parser: '1.0',
  modules: '11',
  node: '0.10.35',
  openssl: '1.0.1j',
  uv: '0.10.30',
  v8: '3.14.5.9',
  zlib: '1.2.8' }
```

---

**EDIT:** Finally a problem is again here, most of the node functions work, but not `http`...

i tested a simple script (from NodeJS API) to get info about a web page:

```
http.get("http://www.google.com/index.html", function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

And I got `Got error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`, is it possible because node is static some features can't work ?

Comment: @artless-noise As you said, I think replacing libraries could be fail all the system, yesterday I tried `mv /lib/libc-2.5.so /share/Public/libc-2.5.so.backup` to know if I could use the server without this lib, and all failed, no more any connections (ftp, http, ssh, telnet...) and I had to reboot the server and the firmware re-installed the library. My goal is to make a newest QPKG for the community, so maybe using static lib could be more useful no ?

Comment: There should be links.  Ie, currently you have '/lib/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.5.so'.  Change this to '/lib/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.19.so'.  The binaries should reference the link and not the physical 'shared library'.  I would experiment in a `chroot` system or you may brick your device (or at least you don't need to reflash).

Comment: Thank you artless noise, I made the chroot jail and `node -v` works perfectly if I override [all of these libs from 2.5 to 2.19](http://pastebin.com/4EY0mcHi). Is there any risk to override for real now ?

Comment: In theory the 2.xx versions should be backwards compatible.  I would test your existing binaries linked to 2.5 (by also copying to `chroot`) and see if they run fine there with symlinks to 2.19.  I am not sure if you are doing this for your self or others?  I am *pretty* sure it is fine, but I wouldn't guarantee it.  It is a benefit to RAM use on the device as opposed to having two copies in memory.  [NodeJs seg-fault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628118/node-js-source-code-build-giving-segmentation-fault-on-arm) question might interest you?

Comment: You could test if you want, here's the [jail folder](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/bfde6e13) and this is [original lib folder](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/ed26b5fc). I know V8 Snapshot doesn't work well on arm machine, I already configure my build to not use it. I have a doubt about my firmware, I think the lib directory is *cleaned* after a reboot of a server, is it possible ? I fear about replace libs manually at each reboot...

Comment: If you don't care about memory, then you can use 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' and have node use a completely separate library.  Ie, both can exist in memory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69416/discussion-between-mickaelb91-and-artless-noise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, instead of trying to change libraries, I decided to have a better cross-compiler which matches with my target perfectly.

I used **[Crosstools-NG](http://crosstool-ng.org/)** for that, but I could use the official **[QNAP Maxwell-ARM Toolchain](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qosgpl/files/QNAP%20NAS%20Tool%20Chains/)** too (I saw it too late...)

```
gcc (GCC) 4.2.4
g++ (GCC) 4.2.4
GNU ld (crosstool-NG 1.20.0) 2.19.1
ldd (crosstool-NG) 1.20.0
Python 2.7.6 (with gyp)
```

But a problem was always here, there's a node dependecy ([libuv](https://github.com/joyent/node/tree/master/deps/uv)) which uses a library named [linux-atomic](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/deps/uv/src/unix/async.c#L108), and that library was introduced in GCC since version 4.4.X. So here is the workaround I made to fix it :

```
cd /src
wget -q https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.6.3/gcc-core-4.6.3.tar.gz
tar -zxf gcc-core-4.6.3.tar.gz
sed -i -e 's/define HIDDEN.*/define HIDDEN/' /src/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/config/arm/linux-atomic.c
export CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
export AR=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar
export RANLIB=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ranlib
cd /src/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/config/arm
libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile $CC -g -O2 -MT linux-atomic.lo -MD -MP -MF linux-atomic.Tpo -c -o linux-atomic.lo linux-atomic.c
$AR cru /src/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/config/arm/.libs/liblinux-atomic.a /src/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/config/arm/.libs/linux-atomic.o
$RANLIB /src/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/config/arm/.libs/liblinux-atomic.a

# IMPORTANT: Assign environment variables like I made in my question above.

# Go to node src dir and configure
./configure --without-snapshot --dest-cpu=arm --dest-os=linux --prefix="${PREFIX_DIR}"

# When configuration is done, edit out/node.target.mk
vi out/node.target.mk

# Find LD_INPUTS files list and add your new library as last one:
# -> /src/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/config/arm/.libs/liblinux-atomic.a

# Now you can build node !
make -j4   #-jX where X is the number of available cores
make install DESTDIR=$TEMPDIR # Use DESTDIR to avoid installation directly in $PREFIX_DIR path
```

[Workaround reference](http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=67956)

With that configuration, I also could compile node with GCC 4.1.3 for x86 processors. And I made QPKG for QNAP users who doesn't want to compile by themselves : https://github.com/jbltx/nodejs-QPKG/tree/master/node-v0.10.35