# BeagleBoneBlack Cross Compile on Mac Error

Tags: c++, arm, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack

I use gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-2014.05 for cross-compling BeagleBoneBlack (Rev c) on my mac using eclipse.

I used this weblog instructions: http://www.welzels.de/blog/en/arm-cross-compiling-with-mac-os-x/

when I compile the hello world sample it works "ok" on BBB, but the problem is when I compile my full program using pthread and stdio and etc... it fails to run on BBB with the following error:

```
./NewDCU.elf: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by ./NewDCU.elf)
```

for more details about my BBB:

```
root@arm:/home/ubuntu# gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.2-19ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --disable-libitm --disable-libquadmath --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-armhf/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-armhf --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-armhf --with-arch-directory=arm --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --enable-multilib --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv7-a --with-fpu=vfpv3-d16 --with-float=hard --with-mode=thumb --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=arm-linux-gnueabihf --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
```

Comment: The Linaro 2014.05 release is GCC 4.9 - you have 4.8 on the device, so a library version mismatch isn't overly surprising. Possible options include: link statically; try an older 4.8-based cross-toolchain; update the libraries on the BBB - depends what you want, really.

Comment: how could I update libraries on BBB?

Comment: See [this question on cross compile of NodeJs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091510/libraries-compatibilty-by-cross-compiling-node-for-armv5), which is the same type of end game.  There are multiple ways to solve the problem.  It depends on if you are just getting it to work for yourself, a distribution, etc.  To start with, the 4.9.2 toolchain has a *sysroot* directory with the C++ *.so* that you need on the device.  You should be able to safely *symlink* it, but test things first in a `chroot` jail.  Also look for a *populate* script; maybe *gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-populate*.

Comment: I tend to just manually copy stuff out of `<toolchain>/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib` into `<NFS root>/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf` for the board, but that's in the context of making a dynamically-linked BusyBox work on a throwaway filesystem for kernel testing - it's probably a terrible idea on a distro filesystem you actually care about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is related to missmatch of toolchain complier version and my corresponding libraries on BBB.

I downgraded my Linaro toolchain to 4.8 from this link:
http://www.welzels.de/blog/projekte/arm-cross-toolchain/