# nodejs segmentation fault on ubuntu 14.04 desktop

Tags: node.js

I have desktop with ubuntu 14.04 LTS. While running command like node,npm,cordova gives me "Segmantation fault" error.

It works fine before couple of hour?

Please advise.

Ask for more information if needed,Thanks for your time and consideration in advance.

-Naitik joshi

Comment: We'd need more details (to clear it for anybody wondering: node doesn't always crash on Ubuntu 14.04). And this isn't probably the best place to help you approach this problem.

Comment: Thanks @dystroy for your quick response,i ran "sudo npm clear cache -f",I think after running this command i got the error now all command like cordova,node,npm gave me same error.I has to settle this ASAP.can you tell we which kind of detail you need?Please..

Comment: I already tried to remove nodejs and reinstall it but no luck

Comment: I found modules file under "/usr/local/lib/node_modules" directory

Comment: Did you search for the answered questions on stackoverflow already? Example of great solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628118/node-js-source-code-build-giving-segmentation-fault-on-arm